# GNU Radio QPSK burst packet from a binary file

Tags: packet, gnuradio

I am struggling trying to implement a packet burst. My data are in a binary file. What I want to do is to send my data in the flow N times per seconds, let's say 2, to simulate a burst transmission.

The "Message Strobe block" seems to be a good candidate but I don't understand how to use it.

Here the (uncorrect) flow I want to have in my transmitter side:
[image]

I tried to get insight from
[Simple GNU Radio Eventstream Based Burst Extraction and Plotting](https://oshearesearch.com/index.php/2015/03/15/a-simple-eventstream-based-burst-plotter-example/) and
[Burst Transmission in GNU Radio Sample Streams with Eventstream](https://oshearesearch.com/index.php/2015/03/15/burst-transmission-in-gnu-radio-sample-streams-with-eventstream/) without success :(

Thank you a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the message strobe block and I build my own block to read a file, build a pmt message and output it directly as a new pdu. It seems to work perfectly well that way :)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have already binary input you have to generate a PDU/message to use Eventstream like shown [here](https://oshearesearch.com/index.php/2015/03/15/burst-transmission-in-gnu-radio-sample-streams-with-eventstream/). As you can see the flowgraph in the article simply adds up the samples produced from noise source and burst transmission. Then you only have to time messages delivered to the Eventstream block. Maybe you can make use of [packetized modems](http://gnuradio.org/doc/doxygen/page_packet_comms.html) freshly introduced with GNU Radio 3.7.10.

Comment: How do I use Eventstream as I don't have the block available in 3.7.10 and I can't install the oot module? Is there an inbox equivalent?

Comment: All right, I managed to install the gr-eventstream modules (was a permission issue).
I will update this post here with my changes.